# get_browser is not returning all the browsers version, it is returning only for Chrome correctly.

Tags: php

get_browser is not returning all the browsers version, it is returning only for Chrome correctly. For IE and Firefox it is returning Default Browser with 0.0 version.

I am having the proper setup of browscap.ini file in C:\wamp\extra folder. And this path is also pointed in php.ini file in Apache/PHP bin folders. Still the correct version is not coming. And another query is if the browser is upgraded in that case browscap.ini file get modified or not automatically ? Please help me guys.

N.B : I am also confused that after configuring these set up I upgraded the version of browser, so that is creating some problem or not, that is also not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [get_browser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), you'll see a very important note:

> Note:
>
> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
> php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
> your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date »
> [php_browscap.ini file here](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/).
>
> While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on
> user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is
> fairly self-explanatory.

If you're stuck on shared hosting and have PHP >=5.3, you should take a look at [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap).

Comment: Actually if I upgrade the browser manually in that case it is not showing version for IE and Firefox ,but showing right version for Chrome, prior to upgrading it was working fine. What is the probable reason of this issue ?